# Non-static method Cartalyst\Sentinel\Sentinel::getUser() should not be called statically

Tags: laravel, cartalyst-sentinel, laravel-auditing

Hi I am using laravel Sentinel as my Auth, also I am trying to use laravel auditing I am getting "Non-static method Cartalyst\Sentinel\Sentinel::getUser() should not be called statically".

In my user model I have added a static function resolveId() for adding user_id in Laravel Auditing 'audits' table

```
public static function resolveId(){
    return Sentinel::getUser()->getUserId();
    //return auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->getAuthIdentifier() : null;
}
```

When I try to use \Sentinel::getUser() I am getting the error below.

```
Non-static method Cartalyst\Sentinel\Sentinel::getUser() should not be called statically
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0#installation):

> After installing the package, open your Laravel config file located at `config/app.php` and add the following lines.
>   In the `$aliases` array add the following facades for this package.

```
'Sentinel' => Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Sentinel::class,
```

Then just add this to the top of the class:

```
use Sentinel;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this `use` on top of the file in question:

```
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Sentinel;
```

Comment: Excellent, you've saved my day. Thank you very much.

Comment: Consider that @AlexeyMenezin answer is a more complete example

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that the package version **@manikandan k** was asking help for is [4.x](http://www.laravel-auditing.com/docs/4.1/general-configuration) or [5.x](http://www.laravel-auditing.com/docs/5.0/general-configuration), and while the documentation does mention the use case for **Sentinel**, it doesn't provide an actual example.

Since version **6.x**, the [Audit Resolvers](http://www.laravel-auditing.com/docs/6.0/audit-resolvers) documentation has this very use case, where **Sentinel** is used instead.

I suggest updating the resolver logic to the following:

```
return Sentinel::check() ? Sentinel::getUser()->getUserId() : null;
```

This will prevent calling `getUserId()` on `null`, when a user isn't logged.